# How to update the new variable into the detail column?

Tags: python, pandas

Here are the new calculate variable that placed in the AF column. However, the old AF variable is wrong and it still in the detail column. As we could see in the diagram, in the 0 row, we see “AF=u”, but the column AF, we find “AF=0.3”. Therefore, we need to correct the new AF variable into the old one. At the 2 row, we see in the detail column, the AF is 3 but we need to correct it as the AF column show, that is the value is 0.7.

The dataframe is like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['A','B','C','z;AC;AD;W;AF=u;Q;R','0.3','G'],
        ['h','k','J','k;5;E;AF=0.6;AG=y;Q;R','0.6','M'],
        ['O','P','Q','k;e;AF=3;W;y;Q;R','0.7','T'],
        ['U','V','W','a;b;AF=0.9;y;Q;R','0.65','Z'],
        ['U','V','W','a;b;AF=0.8;y;Q;R','1','Z']
    ], columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3','detail','AF','Col4'])
```

We get the diagram as below.

[image]

The new column update is easy, but with some character mixed in the column, not just one pure value, it is getting complex.

The expected result is as the diagram below.

[image]

So how to get the result like this diagram?

Answer (score 1):

I feel that you may have more transformations going on in your use case than you have mentioned in your example, So I will start with a general approach. Here is my solution using regex replace and `.apply()`.

```
import re

def myfunc(x, str_pattern):
    return re.sub(str_pattern, f"AF={x['AF']};", x['detail'])

af_pattern = re.compile(r"AF=.+?;") # Pattern to replace
df['detail'] = df.apply(myfunc, axis=1, str_pattern=af_pattern) # Reassign the 'detail' column
```

This method is very general and will accomodate any logic. However, for plain string operations, I would prefer vectorized methods that `pandas` provides by default. These are quite fast.

```
df['detail'] = df.detail.str.split('AF=').str[0] + 'AF=' \  # The part till 'AF='
               + df['AF'] +';' \                            # The correct value
               + df.detail.str.split('AF=').str[1].str.split(';').str[1:].str.join(';') # The last bit
```

Comment: Glad to know. You should consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your dataframe, for the string values in columnn 'detail' - you can modified using the below simple routine - I'm not including pandas functions as that should be straight forward...

```py
>>> s = 'c;D;SD;DF;AF=0.3;Q;W'
>>> l = s.split(';')
>>> modified_list = list(map(lambda x: 'AF=0.5' if x.startswith('AF=') else x, l))
>>> print(modified_list)
['c', 'D', 'SD', 'DF', 'AF=0.5', 'Q', 'W']
>>> print( ';'.join(modified_list) )
c;D;SD;DF;AF=0.5;Q;W
```

In the above example I have hardwired 'AF=0.5' - you can create that string using the AF column value.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it with splitting on the `AF=` and adding in a `|` character instead on the text before the next `;`.

```
pat = r"AF=[^;]*"
repl = "AF=|"
df['temp'] = df['detail'].str.replace(pat,repl)
df['detail'] = df['temp'].str.split('|').str[0].astype(str) + df['AF'].astype(str) + df['temp'].str.split('|').str[1].astype(str)
df = df.drop(columns=['temp'])
```

gives

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3    detail                      AF     Col4
0   A       B       C       z;AC;AD;W;AF=0.3;Q;R        0.3     G
1   h       k       J       k;5;E;AF=0.6;AG=y;Q;R       0.6     M
2   O       P       Q       k;e;AF=0.7;W;y;Q;R          0.7     T
3   U       V       W       a;b;AF=0.65;y;Q;R           0.65    Z
4   U       V       W       a;b;AF=1;y;Q;R              1       Z
```

The only drawback is that detail should not contain the `|` character.  To be safer you could use some craze unicode char.  Also make sure you don't have another column 'temp'.

Comment: Hi Paul, it will left with AF=0.6;.6 and seems  have some character left over.

Comment: Ahhh, missed the `*`after the anything but `;` regex.  fixed